# Create a new list from a given list such that the new list can flag consecutive repetitions in the given list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I have a long list (several hundred thousand items) of numbers and I want to create a new list of equal size to find out the places where there are consecutive repetitions of numbers. The new list will have 0 and 1 values, such that for consecutive repeated indexes the new list will have 1 and for remaining indexes it will have 0 value.

If there is something as a pandas column that can be helpful as well.

Sample given list and resultant array. List can have float values also.

```
given_array = [1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, -2, -4, -6, -8, 9, 9, 9]

result_array = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

I have given a small working example of my code below.

```
import itertools    

def list_from_count(list_item):
    """
    Function takes an iterator and based on the length of the item
    returns 1 if length is 1 or list of 0 for length greater than 1
    """
    if len(list(list_item[1])) == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return [0] * len(list(list_item[1]))

r0 = list(range(1,4))
r1 = [5]*4
r2 = list(range(0,-10,-2))
r3 = [9]*3
r = r0 + r1 + r2 + r3


gri = itertools.groupby(r)
res = list(map(list_from_count,gri))

print ("Result",'\n',res)
```

Result

```
[1, 1, 1, [], 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, []]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `list_from_count` sometimes returns a number, and sometimes returns a list. You need to combine these in such a way that you get a flat list as a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` and output repeated `1`s if the length of a group is greater than 1:

```
from itertools import groupby

result_array = []
for _, g in groupby(given_array):
    size = sum(1 for i in g)
    if size == 1:
        result_array.append(0)
    else:
        result_array.extend([1] * size)
```

or with a list comprehension:

```
result_array = [i for _, g in groupby(given_array) for s in (sum(1 for i in g),) for i in ([0] if s == 1 else [1] * s)]
```

`result_array` becomes:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain/describe this for better understanding?

Comment: Glad to be of help. I've updated my answer with an equivalent code for better clarity on the logics.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `len(list(list_item[1]))` twice. The first time you use it, it processes all the items in the iterator. When you call it the second time, the iterator is all used up, so it returns `0`, that's why you get a zero-element list.

You need to save the length in a variable the first time:

```
def list_from_count(list_item):
    l = len(list(list_item[1]))
    if l == 1:
        return [0]
    else:
        return [1] * l
```

You also need to return a list consistently from this function, then you can concatenate all the results, so you don't get a mix of numbers and sublists.

```
res = []
for el in gri:
    res += list_from_count(el)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

This situation is more akin to a [run length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) problem.  Consider [`more_itertools.run_length`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.run_length):

**Given**

```
import more_itertools as mit


iterable = [1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, -2, -3, -6, -8, 9, 9, 9]
```

**Code**

```
result = [[0] if n == 1 else [1] * n for _, n in mit.run_length.encode(iterable)]
result
# [[0], [0], [0], [1, 1, 1, 1], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Now simply flatten the sub-lists (however you wish) into one list:

```
list(mit.flatten(result))
# [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

---

**Details**

`mit.run_length.encode` compresses an iterable by yielding tuples of (*value*, *# of repititions*), e.g.:

```
list(mit.run_length.encode("abaabbba"))
# [('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 3), ('a', 1)]
```

Our comprehension ignores the value, uses repetitions `n` and creates sub-lists of `[0]` and `[1] * n`.

*Note: [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) is a third-party package.  Install via `> pip install more_itertools`.*

Answer (score 0):

Use the PANDAS `shift` operator to create a vector shifted 1 element.  Compare that to the original.  This will give you a vector of True/False values, showing where an element matched the previous one.  Run a linear search down that list to extend one element at the front: change [False, True] to [True, True].  Convert to `int`, and you have the list you specified.

Comment: Will that do the right thing for the first instance of the repetition?

Comment: The solution will work if there are only two consecutive repetitive elements, but in actual there can be hundreds of repetitions

Comment: No, the shift catches all pairs of consecutive elements.  You can try it, or look up the many examples on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Barmar the second pass extends the `True` values one position to the front, to cover exactly that case.

Comment: @Prune Thanks, I will try this as well and see which solution is faster. Can you please share an example code.